# Period mapping in non-abelian Hodge theory

Tags: kahler-manifolds, hodge-theory, complex-manifolds

Given a family of Kaehler manifolds, by looking at the cohomology we can [construct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Period_mapping) the period mapping. What should be the analogue of the period mapping in non-abelian Hodge theory (i.e. if we look at the fundamental groups, rather than cohomology)?